# Converting datetime to counts?

Tags: r

I would like to convert date to day count and time to hours. I was able to convert datetime to date time with:

```
           data$date <- as.Date(data$datetime)
           data$time <- format(data$datetime,"%H:%M:%S")
           data$datetime<-strptime(as.character(data$datetime),
                                               "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However do not know how to continue. I would like to get the following result:

```
                 date         time       day_count       hours

                2011-01-01  00:00:00         1             0
                2011-01-01  01:00:00         1             1
                2011-01-01  02:00:00         1             2 
                2011-01-01  03:00:00         1             3
                …           … 
                2011-01-02  23:00:00         1            23
                2011-01-02  00:00:00         2             0
                2011-01-02  01:00:00         2             1
                2011-01-02  02:00:00         2             2
                2011-01-02  03:00:00         2             3
                …           …
```

Thank You

Comment: I´m sorry. That was a mistake

Comment: Please provide data for us.  You use something called `data` but we can't run your code without it.  Also where is the function `as.data` from?  Did you mean `as.Date`?

Comment: @Mamba Could you post a `dput` output of a small example dataset ie. `dput(head(data,20))` and the problem you are facing. Also, how do you want the `day_count` to continue after one month.

Comment: actually I thought of just counting the days. ..28,29,30,31,32..

Comment: @Mamba I updated the code. Please check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in `base R` by

```
  data$day_count <- as.numeric(format(data$date, "%d"))
  data$day_count
  #[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

  data$hours <- as.numeric(format(data$datetime, "%H"))
  data$hours
  #[1]  0  1  2  3 23  0  1  2  3
```

#### Update

If you want a continuous count up to a year

```
  as.numeric(format(data$date, "%j")) #will count up to 366 days and then restart
  #[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

i.e.

```
    date1 <-seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), length.out=415, by='1 day')
    Count1 <- as.numeric(format(date1, "%j"))
```

Or you can modify the restarted count every month.  Suppose `v1` is your `day_count`

```
  v1 <- rep(c(rep(1:31, each=5), rep(1:30, each=4)),2)
  indx <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(v1)<0))
  indx1 <- tapply(v1, cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(v1)<0)), max)
  v2 <- unname(v1+rep( c(0,cumsum(indx1[-1])), table(indx)))
```

#### data

```
  data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
  14976, 14976, 14976, 14976, 14976), class = "Date"), time = c("00:00:00", 
  "01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
  "02:00:00", "03:00:00"), datetime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L), mday = c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
 111L, 111L, 111L), wday = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
 ), yday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), isdst = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", "EST", "EST", 
"EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
 NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
 NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", 
 "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("date", 
"time", "datetime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Im sorry to bother you again. But there is one unexpected consequence of your suggestion. the count restarts after each month. when i introduce,as.numeric(format(data$date,"%m-%d")) or data$day2<-as.numeric(format(data$date,"%m:%d")) i get Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Lubridate library to handle the datatime objects, it makes everything much easier. I'm also going to use dplyr library to deal with the dataframe

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

date <- c("2011-01-01", "2011-02-07", "2014-09-11")
time <- c("00:05:00", "12:42:00", "19:11:00")

df <- tbl_df(data.frame(date= ymd(date), time= hms(time)))
df <- mutate(df, day_count= day(date), hours= hour(time))
```

Output:

```
> df

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

        date       time day_count hours
1 2011-01-01      5M 0S         1     0
2 2011-02-07 12H 42M 0S         7    12
3 2014-09-11 19H 11M 0S        11    19
```

Comment: sorry to bother you with that simple question but what data type is date & time in your case. Il get for the first df Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: i followed the code of akrun. Still thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: date is `"POSIXct", "POSIXt"` and time is `"Period"`

Answer (score 0):

Get the hour (0-23):

```
 mydate = strptime('2011-01-02  23:00:00',format='%H')
```

Get the numerical day of week (0-6 with Sunday as 0):

```
mydate = strptime('2011-01-02  23:00:00',format='%w')
```

References:

[Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

[Berkeley](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)